# How to awake from sleep in unix

Tags: unix

```
file_count="any command to find file count in directory."

while [ $file_count -eq 0 ]
do

if [ $file_count -eq 0 ]
then
    sleep 6000
    continue
else
    break
fi

done
```

---

The question here is what if my files recieved in directory(not specified here) before time i.e. 1 hr.
Do I need to wait to complete 1 hr always?
Is there any way if files recieved in between and then I want to come out from sleep state?
Please help.

Comment: As it stands, you never change the value in `$file_count`, so your loop will never terminate.  Also, 6000 seconds is an hour and 40 minutes or thereabouts.  The only ways to know that a file has appeared are to poll for it (run `ls` or whatever) or to use an event system such as Inotify.  If you want to know more quickly than the time delay, choose a smaller time delay.  If your command is not too expensive, you could change 6000 to 600 (10 minutes) or 300 (5 minutes) or 60 (1 minute).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 
_$file_count_ will be updated so no issue about it.Its just example I have provided here.
Also,
can I use **Inotify** to check that file is available(will be sent from other server) to come out of sleep mode?

Comment: You can read the manual for Inotify just as well as I can.  You might need to completely restructure your testing — but Inotify can report when files appear or disappear (aka the directory holding them changes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Inotify](http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring) to check for file system events.

Comment: can you please give example, if '$file_count' gets increase in between Inotify can be used.